# Trying to redirect browser tab if coincidence in title - Tampermonkey

Tags: redirect, match, tampermonkey, auto

Im trying to search a word in the **title** or **Body** of the tab and if **coincidence**, redirect to another page, using Tampermonkey, this is the code that I found:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto Cerrar
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @icon         *

// ==/UserScript==

// Your code here...
(function() {
var blacklist = ["potato", "onion", "put other text here"],
    re = new RegExp(blacklist.join('|'), "i");
if (re.test(document.body.textContent)) {
window.open("https://www.google.com","_self");
alert("Coincidence Found!")
}
})();
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `if (blacklist.some(term => document.body.textContent.includes(term))) window.location.href = "https://www.google.com"`

Comment: Trying and working directly